# How can I create a method for the type bool in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a new method called 'reverse' to be able to change a boolean value into the opposite value, so if the value is currently true the method should return false and vice versa.

I changed the bool.dart file in my project and created the new method below the 'toString()' method

```
bool reverse() {
    return this ? false : true;
  }
```

and afterwards I used the method for my '_isLoading' boolean variable but I got this error.

> Error: The method 'reverse' isn't defined for the class 'bool'. Try
> correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a
> method named 'reverse'.
> _isLoading.reverse();
> ^^^^^^^

I exited the reading mode in my bool.dart file and that also didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add something to bool class, try this:

```
extension on bool {
  bool reverse() {
    return this ? false : true;
  }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
bool x = false;
x.reverse(); // return true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
main(){
  var a = false;
  print(a); //false
  var b =a.reverse();
  print(b); //true
}

extension on bool{
  bool reverse(){
    return !this;
  }
}
```

**More Shorter version:**

```
extension on bool{
  bool reverse() => !this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool reverse(bool currentValue) {
    return !currentValue; // ! will return the reverse
  }
```